# Activity Crashes after adding Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a activity where i use a custom library for my gauges and here is my code

```
package com.smart_farming.smart_farming_app;

public class DeviceCards extends AppCompatActivity {

    View view =  null;
    private pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge moistureGauge, humidityGauge, temperatureGauge;
    int soil;
    int humidity;
    int temp;

    private static final String TAG = "DeviceCards";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_cards);

        moistureGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.soil_moisture_gauge);
        humidityGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.humidity_gauge);
        temperatureGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.temp_gauge);
        TextView lols = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("soilMoisture").child("moisture");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                int  resultSoil = Integer.parseInt(value);
                moistureGauge.setValue(resultSoil);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### This is my firebase schema

[image: schema]

### Also is this normal

[image]

There are now error except when i open the app the activity crashes.

Comment: Post the stracktrace.

Comment: To let people dig into this, divulge your firebase database structure and the error statement.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please!

Comment: To answer your "Also is this normal" question about the annotation - this is a linter warning that you should mark the DataSnapshot param as @NonNull since that's the way it was declared in ValueEventListener.  If you don't mark with an annotation, nullable is assumed.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question and please responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

Change From

```
moistureGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.soil_moisture_gauge);
humidityGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.humidity_gauge);
temperatureGauge = view.findViewById(R.id.temp_gauge);
TextView lols = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

To

```
moistureGauge = findViewById(R.id.soil_moisture_gauge);
humidityGauge = findViewById(R.id.humidity_gauge);
temperatureGauge = findViewById(R.id.temp_gauge);
TextView lols = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Since its Activity findViewById is enough.